Thread suspending and resuming
The essence of the program is the implementation of methods for pausing, resuming and stopping the flow-of-control across threads.
Code taken from Herbert Schildt's Java: A Beginner's Guide, Ninth Edition, Chapter 12. I didn’t write it exactly, but I think the essence is clear.
class MyThread implements Runnable{

    Thread thrd;
    boolean suspended;
    boolean stopped;

    MyThread(String name){

        thrd= new Thread(this,name);
        suspended=false;
        stopped=false;
    }

    public static MyThread createAndStart(String name){

        MyThread mt = new MyThread(name);
        mt.thrd.start();
        return mt;
    }

    public void run(){

       try{
           for(int i=1;i<1000;i++){
               System.out.print(i + " ");
               if(i%10==0){
                   System.out.println();
                   Thread.sleep(250);
               }

               synchronized(this){
                   while(suspended) wait();
                   if(stopped) break;
               }
           }
       }

       catch(InterruptedException e){
       } 
    }

    synchronized void myStop(){

        stopped=true;
        suspended=false;
        notify();
    }

    synchronized void mySuspend(){

        suspended = true;
    }

    synchronized void myResume(){
        suspended=false;
        notify();
    }

}

public class Suspend {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        MyThread mt1 = MyThread.createAndStart("Thread 1");
        try{

            Thread.sleep(1000);
            mt1.mySuspend();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            mt1.myResume();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            mt1.mySuspend();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            mt1.myResume();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            mt1.mySuspend();
            mt1.myStop();
        }

        catch(InterruptedException e){
        }
    }
}

Now to my questions:

My brain refuses to understand the synchronized(this) construction.  Why is it needed if the methods are already synchronized?  And what are we synchronizing in this block?  While and if statements???
Why is Thread.sleep() used in the main method if the essence of synchronization is for threads to automatically gain access to the object?
In the book, in previous exercises, a separate class was usually created, and through its methods the threads would already do their jobs, but in this program, the class itself is used for this, which implements the Runnable interface.  What the hell is this anyway??!  I would be very grateful for clarifications


As for #5, this would be terrible code for practical real-world work. I assume this code is meant as a contrived example to deliver an educational message. In real work in modern Java we rarely address the Thread class directly. Instead we submit Runnable/Callable objects to an ExecutorService object. That is why the Executors framework was added to Java 5, to relieve us Java programmers of the burden of juggling threads.

By the way, your English is good. I tweaked your writing a bit in my edits, but your prose was entirely understandable.

If you need more material to better understand this broad topic, I suggest you to take a look at the concurrency section of Java tutorials. I personally think that it's quite well done and helps a lot if it's your first time with it. I'll leave you the link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html

By the way, a larger lesson here is to make your background tasks independent of one another if at all possible. Coordinating across threads is tricky business.



Why is it needed if the methods are already synchronized?


It isn't. However, the only place synchronized (this) is used, is in the run() method, which does not have the synchronized keyword.
Hence, trivially, it is needed there. Note that invoking x.wait() or x.notify() (or, of course, notifyAll) when you are not in a synchronized (x) block will immediately throw an exception because you can't do that unless you are synchronized on it. In other words, that synchronized is definitely a requirement.
NB: Note that if you call x.wait(), the 'lock' on x is released, and x.wait() does not return (i.e. your code will not continue) until both things have occurred: [A] some other thread invoked x.notify() / x.notifyAll(), and [B] this thread re-acquires that lock on x. Which by definition it cannot instantly do, because whatever thread called x.notify() necessarily currently has it (or, they wouldn't have been able to invoke notify on x!).


why is Thread.sleep() used in the main method if the essence of synchronization is for threads to automatically gain access to the object?


The intent of the example is that this is a standin for 'some arbitrary task that takes some time'. It represents 'do some complex math', 'interact with the network or disk or some other relative-to-the-CPU slow external thing'. It's not about 'sleep' and if you had an actual job to do, you wouldn't use sleep here.


What the hell is this anyway??!


It's a book of some sort, I gather. I'm not sure what further information you expected here, this part of your question isn't very clear.
The point of this tutorial is to show you how to add the ability to pause or abort any thread that repeatedly (as in, in a loop) performs a task. This model (of a thread that just does a job over and over again, forever) is extremely common. For example, a thread that captures log info and sends it on both to disk and to another source, to ensure you have logs even if the disk hard-crashes (or a hacker deletes the logs after compromising your system), but, you don't want the system to be slowed down (i.e. a log message should not wait around for any of that and just keep going - thus, requiring a thread). Or, a thread that is connected to some messaging service and just grabs a message (which will wait (i.e the method call just sits there, not returning) until an actual message is available), inspect it to know which code knows how to handle it, hands it off to that code and then.. loops and does the same thing over and over again.
Specifically:

There is no generalized 'pause thread' concept in java. You have to program it.

To do so, one way (this book merely explains one way, there are many) is to, as part of your loop, check a boolean flag and, if it indicates the thread is suspended, to invoke wait().

It highlights that you should do that in a while, not an if - generally you always want to explicitly check flags; you do not want to take the fact that your wait() method returned, itself, as a signal of anything other than 'time to check the flag again'.

It highlights how any communication of any sort between 2 threads by way of modifying fields must never be done unless synchronized is there to ensure that the field write is actually guaranteed to be observable by the other thread. Without a Happens-Before relationship (and synchronized is one common and easy way to establish one), the JVM makes no guarantees that thread B can actually see the modifications to a field that thread A made. So without synchronized, one thread can set suspended = true, and the other thread can continue to believe that value is false for a year if it wants to. The Java Virtual Machine Specification explicitly calls out that's a valid thing for a JVM to do _if there is Happens-Before, such as established with synchronized.



"It's a book of some sort" just brilliant xDD. Also, great in-depth answer. You have my laugh and my upvote!
